Advantages and disadvantages of outrigger ships
I'm designing boats and ships for a medieval seafaring civilization. I thought about basing their ships on Filipino outrigger boats. But then I wondered what the advantages and disadvantages of outrigger designs are. Sadly I couldn't find much info on historic vessels as most content is focused on modern sailing yachts and not on the development of ships.
So far I found these advantages:

better stability
shallow draft
hydrodynamic efficiency

And these disadvantages:

smaller size (unsure if large outrigger ships are impossible or where just not needed)
lower load capacity
paddles not oars (there are mentions of oars used for karakoas but no images I saw featured oars and the outrigger might interfere with them)

So please let me know what I forgot and why outriggers are generally not seen in Europe.

Basing their ships on any kind of boats is maybe not the best approach. And seafaring means sails not oars or paddles; oars are fine for maneuvering and such, but a ship carrying a significant amount of cargo over a distance of more than a few miles needs sails.

There's always cats (twinned hulls).

@Escapeddentalpatient. I'm aware of catamarans and how they are closely related to outrigger ships. However they also weren't used in much of the world. The question is why where mono hull vessels the standard in most of the world.

@AlexP Perhaps I should have said sea vessel instead of ship or boat which are inherently linked to certain sizes. The Philippines had not only outrigger boats but also ships like the karakoa or the lanong.

Both the karakoas and the lanongs were men-of-war, corresponding to the ancient triremes and medieval galleys in European history. A true sea-faring civilization must be capable of trading across the seas.

As I am reading this question - it is unclear as to whether this is a Worldbuilding question - or a History question. It could be a Worldbuilding question (and a very interesting one at that) - or it could be a Historical question about Maritime technology in different regions (also an interesting question)

Searching on "Polynesian outriggers" or "Why European ships did not use outriggers" gives a plethora of useful results on the evolution and history of both single hull and multi-hull/outrigger craft.  Other than that, look at your use case for what you want your boats/ships to do in your setting and see if outriggers meet that need or not.

@TheDemonLord It's a bit of both. I want to base this civilization on the sama bajau and polynesians as those focused heavily on life in and around water. And one interesting trait I found is that they used many outrigger and multi hull ships that weren't used in Europe. So I try to understand what the advantages and disadvantages of their ships where and if that would fit the setting and the story. For example using crab claw sails and shunting is something I don't like as it makes naval chases slower.

@KerrAvon2055 Perhaps you are better at googling then me but I couldn't find a reason why outriggers weren't used in Europe. I know how outriggers where developed from rafts and that they give ships additional stability. But I couldn't find something about their disadvantages, but since not everyone is using them there have to be drawbacks with that design.

@GreedyGroot that focus on naval warfare, rather than trade, fishing etc, needs to be edited into the question - there are some obvious and not-so-obvious reasons that outriggers are less desirable.

@GreedyGroot - I am not going to VTC this - but the question does need to be re-worded. If you want a Historical answer - then we are not the right place for it - if you want some worldbuilding answers as to why they would or would not use Outriggers - we can certainly look at that. As I said - I think this has the bones of a great an interesting quesiton - but needs a touch more work :)

For future reference, per the [help/dont-ask], providing your own answers and asking for more is prohibited. Asking more than one question is literally a reason to close a question (you're asking three: advantages, disadvantages, and why they're not seen in European history). I found an example of large outriggers at wikipedia. And please note, Stack Exchange's purpose is to help you solve specific problems. It's not really a free research service. I'm also not seeing a worldbuilding problem here.

@JBH In that large outrigger example, the Borobudur ship the outriggers seem way too small to provide sufficient stability on their own. Most of the stability will need to come from the main hull.
I found https://www.wuestenschiff.de/Phoenicia/Boro_Exped.pdf which gives more insight into that ship and confirms my suspicion.

@AlexP Got to be careful with the term "out rigger" because it means more than 1 thing. Lanongs were single hulled ships with a structure that extends out of the upper deck (also called an outrig) which made it easier for ships with multiple levels of oarsmen to row without getting in each other's way.  This kind of outrig has nothing to do with the Philippine out rig which the OP is asking about.

@LazyLizard From an engineering perspective, the larger the ship, the less the need for outriggers due to the stability you mention. There may have been no truly large outriggers historically simply because once you have enough breadth and draft underwater their purpose ceases. That makes your comment a valuable insight that could be built, I believe, into an excellent answer.

Hogging and Sagging
On a calm sea, a ship submerges to the point where displacement equals load. But the load is not spread equally over the volume, so there are bending stresses on the hull.
Now take a sea which is not calm. If a ship is on a wave crest, the bow and stern are not supported and bend down. If the ship is in a wave trough, the center is not supported and bends down. These are dynamic changes, not static. The term for that is hogging and sagging.
There is a tradeoff between the structural stability of the watercraft and the prevention of rolling. A large catamaran or trimaran hull is more difficult to design and construct than a large monohull. In recent years there were some large SWATH hulls, but those would be impossible without steel.

To this cane be added that sideways waves will tilt the ship a lot - imagine the outrigger on the crest of a tall wave, with the main hull at the bottom. If you have two outriggers, the stress will be enormous if both are on crests and the main hull in the valley between.

[more difficult than] Do you mean "more difficult to construct than"?

@gs. yes, clarified.

Outriggers are terrible for pre-modern naval combat
Based on your comment to @TheDemonLord it appears that you are interested in the vessel type you settle on being used for naval combat.  So, let's start by examining all the known occasions in which Polynesian / south-east Asian outrigger vessels engaged in significant naval combat prior to European influence during the Age of Sail.
...
Well, that was slightly surprising.  While "lack of evidence is not evidence of lack" and the Pacific Ocean is notably deeper than the Mediterranean (therefore better at concealing wrecks), there does not appear to be any indication of significant intership battles.  Many of the people using outrigger vessels were warlike and, as noted in Kilisi's answer there were definitely war canoes, but they appear to have only used boats/ships to transport troops to other islands to engage in land battles.  Rather than speculating about why the relevant people did not choose to engage in naval warfare, let's look at why outriggers are terrible choices for naval engagements at that tech level.
In naval battles from the Punic Wars up until the Age of Sail, there were two primary methods of eliminating enemy ships:

Ram them, in order to cripple or sink them.
Board them, in order to preferably capture the vessel or at least cause damage before withdrawing.

These were not the only weapons in play - bows and other ranged weapons would be used to target the enemy crew while closing - but these were the decisive options.  Outriggers are terrible at both, as:

In order to ram, the ship will win that successfully manoeuvres so that it can strike the flank of the enemy vessel with the ram mounted on its bow.  For an attacking outrigger, this is going to cause massive stress to the outrigger as the ship basically comes to a halt from ramming speed and the outrigger on the end of a long arm wants to keep going.  Alternatively, if it attacks at an oblique angle then the outrigger may strike first.  In either case, it is far too likely that the impact will critically damage the outrigger, making for a mutual kill.  For the defending ship, the outrigger hull itself is a weakness that, if rammed, will result in the ship capsizing or being critically reduced in manoeuverability (depending on whether the outrigger hull shatters and/or breaks free of the arms it is mounted on).
In order to board an enemy vessel, the deck of the attacking ship must be high enough that troops can step straight onto the other ship once they are alongside.  The outrigger hulls are too low to the water to allow this, meaning that a vessel with outrigger hulls on both sides can only board by ramming, with the problems mentioned above.  (Pirate movies may show that climbing a rope up onto an enemy ship's deck with a knife clenched in the teeth is a viable way of boarding from a lower-level deck - history disagrees.)  An attacking ship with an outrigger on only one side attempting to board is very predictable, as they can only approach from one side.

For further reading and consideration, suggest that you look through the list of naval battles of the medieval period, and consider how outrigger ships would have fared against the single-hull vessels that were in use.

European ships evolved from low, long ships into ships with multiple decks. One reason was being able to shoot arrows and cannon down into the other ship. A low ship couldn't shoot cannon up into the upper decks.

Outriggers are best suited for small and light vessels
Adding outriggers to a boat/ship does the following:

Firstly it slows it down because there now is more drag in the water. It only becomes advantageous in that regard if you can optimize the main hull to make up for this. Fortunately one way to do that is removing unneeded ballast, reducing wetted area and drag because the outrigger stabilizes the boat. Another way is to make the hull shape more advantageous by making it slimmer and longer that it would be possible for a mono hull, wich also reduces drag and increases hull speed (the maximum speed for a displacement hull).

Here is the first catch, for a cargo vessel, most of that ballast is your cargo, you don't want to remove it. And building a longer, slimmer hull with the same displayment is more expensive and technically challenging.
When an even bigger monohull with more cargo capacity can be build for the same investment, the outrigger option doesn't look like such a good idea.

Another effect is, for the same overall stability you vessel will stay more upright, which is more comfortable, but more important, makes your sails more efficient so you go a bit faster.

This is a plus cargo vessels could also benefit from.
But there is also a catch to this, a monohull leans over in a gust, reducing the effective sail area, taking load out of the sails and rigging until it is in equilibrium again.
An outrigger takes the full brunt of the wind force until a specific point where the buoyancy of the outrigger is insufficient, and your vessel suddently and dramatically leans over, or something breaks.
So it is more prone to sudden catastrophic failure.

Regarding failures, the attachments of the outriggers will experience significant load, making larger vessels challenging to build, especially if you are limited to wood as a building material.

A practical downside is that multihulls take up significantly more space than an equivalent monohull. This is mostly relevant when docking in a harbor.


Real world examples of larger outrigger boats
Examples taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outrigger_boat, as was remarked in the comments.
Examples of larger outriggers boats would be indonesian Juanga and Borobudur (known from a temple relief).
Both seem to have rather small outriggers for their size.
For the Joungas this can be understood by looking at their propulsion, theses are warships with relatively small sails and additional propulsion by oars, so these are in need of less stability to counteract the wind.
For the Borobudurs a modern reconstruction was build and tested, I found further information in this source:
https://www.wuestenschiff.de/Phoenicia/Boro_Exped.pdf
It is remarked there that the outriggers are in themselfes insufficient for stability, even seemed to slow it down quite a bit. Most of its stability has to come from its hull, so it is really more of a hybrid.
Conclusion
So all in all, for a merchant ship with the goal of lugging around tons of goods as cheap as possible its not a good fit.
For personal transport, or light but valuable goods it can be, but you better have a crew that knows how to properly handle it.
Real world examples indicate that there were limitations on outrigger size, limiting the vessel size that can take full advantage of them.

the point about the drag is wrong. On the contrary, having more than one hull is advantageous if it helps reduce the length-to-width-ratio to better than 8:1

@Burki No, the point is you only get benefits if you modify the main hull to be smaller and lighter, which you really dont want if the goal is cargo space.
Maybe you can get a net benefit by adding outriggers AND making the hull longer and narrower, keeping the displacement the same. I would love to see numbers for this, my gut feeling is the benefit would be small (and the vessel more expensive to build).

It needn't be smaller and lighter. It just needs to be slim. Two slim hulls with the same overall volume result in a faster speed.

@Burki The question is not about cats but outriggers. Sure two hulls with the same volume will give more speed, but will also be almost twice as expensive to build on their own, even before we even talk about firmly attaching them together.
This basically amounts to "just build a bigger ship", which indeed is always more efficient but quickly becomes impractical because of monetary and engineering restrictions.

You have a point there. However, i was assuming that the outrigger design would have evolved from boats over to ships, rather than just adding outriggers to a galleon, or trireme, or similar. Hence i think your statement about added drag doesn't hold. But it would, if it was really just adding outriggers to an existing monohull.

I edited my answer to include hull shape and the ecomic implications of it.

TL;DR: shallow-draft vessels are inherently unstable, especially in rougher conditions. Outriggers especially evolved to address that weakness. Also, where they are popular, there are no good materials for deep-water shipbuilding of large-sized vessels.
It is very, very important to the topic to remember that Polynesian sailing vessels were fast, maneuverable and surprisingly resilient,but they were all basically rafts. Them being superior navigators, they usually were going around the storm or made landfall to weather it. In worst cases they deployed sea anchors and intentionally flooded their boats, so that they floated just under the surface and they clung to them. However, in cases of severe storm that would not be enough, simply because of the earlier point: rafts, essentially. Communications, limited trade - yes, between close locations. Warfare - same. Crossing blue ocean hundreds of miles - rarely on purpose, mostly by accident.
This is in stark contrast to other places, where evolution of sea going vessels were emphasizing size in every place sea was important, but the main difference was the raw material quality - oak is much better for carvel hull or a junk than palm or bamboo, and having good shelter from storms made away with having to beach ships to protect them.
Longer answer:
Who said outriggers aren't/weren't seen in Europe? Even today they are very popular recreational sailboats (catamaran/trimaran).
The difference is that Europe is very unique in many regards, but for this topic there are three:

European shoreline is longer than Africa's. This means quite a lot of land is close enough to the shore to be considered coastal area, where population is densest, and it offers protection from rough conditions, basically along all of the European coast. This allowed for building bigger ships, that don't have to be beached. Pair that with a river network allowing for extending that access to areas often quite far from the sea, and you'll see the importance of sailing for the economy.
Europe had easy access to high-to-highest quality materials for shipbuilding. The wood best suited for making boats needs to meet certain criteria, which are not reachable for a lot of places on Earth
Taking the two of the above into account, Europe placed greatest weight on the water-based transportation and communication. This in turn propelled constant improvement and then technological breakthroughs: from Viking longships/knarrs to cogs to caravels to galleons to indiamen to finally barques.

In greatest summary: European-style ships were most efficient designs for the purpose of travel long distance by water, reducing drift caused by the wind with the keel (sometimes with added centerline board and/or fin, increasing draft, but also stability), faster with carvel-hull (smooth hull) and with sails allowing to sailing much closer to the wind.
Last one requires more explanation: sail ships are propelled by wind, so the trick is to convert the wind - from any direction - into the movement forward. Obviously sailing against the wind is impossible, but what about wind from behind, from the side or even somewhat from the "front" of the boat? Answer is in sailing in the general direction, which we want to go, but only as far off-course as possible, just enough to still be propelled by the wind ("beating to winward"). Sail ships can use any wind except from about 45 degrees to the either side (from the "front"). But that means that ship travels longer distance and for longer time. So every bit helps: the closer to the wind it can go the better, the least it can drift (move to the side, pushed by the wind off-course), the faster it can go the better. And each has cumulative effect on the distance and time travelled, and the farther the trip the greater the rewards.
None of these are available to outriggers, making them great for fast travel between points relatively close to each other. Of course Austronesians were using outriggers to cross huge swaths of the Pacific's, but that wasn't as efficient as possible and, of course, extremely dangerous, regardless of the size of the outrigger ship.

Polynesians routinely went for 100's of miles in outriggers. Why do you think it was 'extremely dangerous'? Our fishermen here think nothing of going out into the ocean for a few days until they've caught their fill.

@Kilisi Because in case of storm they can lose their boat to waves (freak wave can break the outrigger), certainly it will capsize several times, the storm can last for days and due to size of the boat supplies are limited, and water can damage them easily (even if boat won't capsize), it can take the boat even hundreds of miles off position/course... All is fine if weather is fine, if weather goes bad... all bets are off. I'd say this rule of thumb is good enough: anything that needs to be pulled on the beach for protection - in case of storm - is not suited for blue water travels...

I think you greatly underestimate the seaworthiness of these craft and/or the skills of the sailors., and the provisions even... good luck damaging a coconut

@Kilisi - Well, you are right to your opinion, but I am not making this stuff up. I am an experienced sailor. Granted, my "blue sea" experience is much lesser than I would like, but I know a thing or two about violent storms in a sailboat. There is not much skill involved in those except "hold the f**k on to something!", there's way more praying the tub will hold together and will not flip (capsize)...

Another aspect is to travel in groups of boats. If one boat breaks in a storm, the other boats can help.

@DavidR - then again, in most cases the help can be rendered only AFTER the storm, and groups and storms meeting tend to end up with boats scattered all around. Depending on how long the storm will last the boats may end up beyond visual range, effectively breaking the group for a while.

That's hardly applicable to a Polynesian outrigger, capsizes you just flip it back, but they don't capsize easily, it's kind of the whole point of the outrigger. Provisions couldn't care less about being submerged. Only real danger is being blown so far off course you can't get back and live the rest of your life wherever you eventually wind up, but that doesn't happen these days.

@Kilisi - this is hardly the argument for outriggers, taking into account that they are not, and basically never were, anything but a dead end in shipbuilding developement. They are used today, true, but there is a reason for it, and it's not they are better in any way.

@AcePL you make no sense to me sorry. If they're in use for a few thousand years they work fine.

@Kilisi - where are they used? For what? What impact they have on the technological/civilizational progress? We in Europe also use small and medium sailboats - from single seater to 20+ crew size. But I don't see them used COMMERCIALLY, MILITARILY OR INDUSTRIALLY. This is my point, and just a quick peek on a Philippine-based shipyard's website, they recommend aluminum rather than bamboo. Do I make sense now, please?

@AcePL no, you're still typing nonsense, no offense.

"no, you're still typing nonsense, no offense" - none taken. I don't know how to dumb down more what I wrote, sorry. So let's leave it at that.

Large outriggers were known about it Europe, they just were not preferred.
Fairly large, multi-hull ships were common in Ancient Egypt around 300BCE where they saw some use throughout the Eastern Mediterranean for a short while but they were slowly phased out due to thier limitations, with the last of the multihull ships being made sometime around 400CE.  Given how much contact and trade Egypt had with the Rest of Europe during this time period it is inconceivable that other Europeans would have been unaware of multi-hull ships. Catamarans worked out just fine for the Egyptians for thier local maritime needs, but they were notoriously "calm weather only" ships.  The storms seen in Western Europe were simply too common and too rough which the Egyption Catamarans could not endure.  As Egypt became a more prominent trading power, thier need for ships that could handle rougher weather become more important than the stability that they offered.
Why a Civilization might prefer them
If your nation cares more about traversing major Rivers like the Nile or Mississippi than actual Seas and Oceans as the Ancient Egyptians did, then a culture of fairly large catamarans makes since.  If a storm comes, rivers tend not to get big waves like you get in more open bodies of water; so, snapping is less of an issue and the shallower hulls means you are less likely to get stuck on a sand bank.  As for oars, consider a catamaran instead of the useless outriggers like you see on canoe sized boats.  When your outrigger is a hull unto itself, they actually have more room for oarsmen because you can have oars on the outside and inside of your design with the ship connected by a higher deck.
As for possible military applications, a multi-hull ship offers more stability for aiming and firing ranged weapons; so, if your civilization has an effective incendiary projectile, the added stability could give you a greater effective range in naval combat which would offset disadvantage of lower maneuverability and complications with ramming and boarding warfare.

I read now multiple times that multi hull/outrigger designs are not meant for harsh open seas. However there is evidence that polynesian people successfully reached south America.

@GreedyGroot thier ships were much smaller than European ships.  A 25-30ft boat is adequate to get a couple of people across the ocean, but if you plan to trade, colonize, or engage in large scale warfare, you need something much bigger.  Most long range European ships from ancient Greece onwards were at least 60ft long with many exceeding 120ft.  It's not that you can't make a deep-sea multi-hull ship, it's that you can't make them big enough to both cross oceans and serve the needs of a larger civilization.

The Egyptians actually built large multihull trade ships, but they were mostly used for traversing the Nile where thier larger size did not work against them.

They grew out of different ship building traditions. Medieval times with outriggers or better still doubled hulled ships would be superior in speed, handling and manouvering if they combined medieval technology with Pacific Island tech. But they'd be pretty useless in a fight.
The reason they didn't grow to great size in Polynesian is the lack of metal tech mostly. These were stone age societies, so a hull is as big as the tree you cut it from. Try fastening it together in pieces with sennit or other fibre and you can expect it to rip itself to bits mid voyage. So they'll build up the sides with planks, but not the base hull.
But these were not war canoes. War canoes were a totally different technology, built for great speed to transport a bunch of warriors for a few days. Not to transport a lot of gear. And again, size constrained. These would engage in naval battles on some occasions but they didn't have outriggers.

This is my setting. Maybe it'll help you.
Your fictional society could have a love of hydraulics too if you want primitive but sophisticated tech. Barrels on a lever arm raised and lowered by the waves to pump hydraulic fluid (water) with bronze pumps and leather or wooden tubes to rotate propellers or cyclorotors which can be wood or bronze. Vertical axis wind turbines to do the same. A more complex but still medieval tech practical hydraulic oars. The motion of oars where you use the whole body, but bolted to a wall and pumping hydraulic fluid. Waves average 20 kilowatts per sq meter so it be a rather fast ocean going vessel.
Ramming would work by raising the individual barrels when about to be rammed. You don't have to raise them when your doing the ramming. The barrels is just an empty wine barrel with a 2 by 4 as the lever arm. Hydraulically loaded arbalists would be awesome. Basically rapid firing spears for arrows. One could have a hydraulically powered friction wheel furnace for cooking and hot water. A washing machine. A variety of modern day appliances are just heat and rotating/reciprocating mechanisms. Essentially luxury pirates who have a reason to have both very large and very fast ships.
Sure the outriggers help with stability but the primary thing is for wave powered propulsion and capturing the wind equally well in all directions. Luxuries on the side.
Let me know if this helps.
